# How to design the page and print it on the thermal printer on Epson TM-T88V POS Printer

Tags: c#, html, barcode

I am creating the Web Application, After completion of payment i need to get the receipt from the Epson TM-T88V POS Printer in c# using ASP.Net. and after displaying the relevant information on the paper i need to display the Barcode also.

Will it possible to design the page and print it.

Thanks in advance,
Vara Prasad.M

Comment: Connection to the printer must be at the server, is that truly what you want?

Comment: @Vara How are you using print receipt using web application?
Can you please give a solution for that, i am also confused about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure this can be done, however I suspect you are wanting it to be seamless, which can't be done without Silverlight, Java or another embedded solution.

What you can do however is use HTML/CSS and a Barcode image generator to create a page that contains your receipt, then you can simply print via the browser onto your thermal printer.

The only thing that you may find is that your browser often adds a header/footer to your pages and these will appear on your receipt.

A better solution is to use the Silverlight or Java to handle this, as it would have direct communication with the printer, rather than having to rely on the browser.

Link to a possible barcode generator.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20823/Barcode-Image-Generation-Library